# JS Maps Library - Brazil Based

Tags: javascript, highcharts, maps

We are developing an application that will need to use this JS library but based on the map of Brazil with states and cities.

Does anyone know a solution?

(Google Translate)

Comment: Did you look at the map collection? http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/mapdata/countries/br/br-all. I believe these are states. Not sure about cities - but you can by giving lat/lon to highmaps for the cities: https://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/mappoint-latlon

Comment: Here you can find the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wu8kyoab/ where Rio de Janerio is added using lat\lon coordinates.